# How to export/import host headers from IIS7 website?

Tags: iis-7, iis-7.5

I have an application which has 55 host headers. How can I copy those bindings to a different application within the same IIS?

Comment: Programmatically or will any method do?

Answer (score 23):

Ok take care by doing this...

Go to: C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config and open applicationHost.config

This file has all the sites configurations.

Find the correct site and copy the binding information to another site.

Comment: I'm using windows server 2012, no such file is found

Comment: @AliBehzadianNejad the path is unchanged on Windows Server 2012 - but this folder is probably not accessible to your regular user account. run your editor as administrator and you should be able to see it. actually you need to do this on server 2008 also

Answer (score 0):

Why not just copy the content from the source site's httpProtocol tag in the web.config and paste it for the rest of the target sites. For me it is a simpler approach as I couldn't find this info in this file - `C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config`

```
        <httpProtocol>
            <customHeaders>
                <remove name="X-Powered-By" />
                <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="https://myserver/mysite/" />
                <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
                <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS" />
                <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true" />
                <add name="Referrer-Policy" value="strict-origin-when-cross-origin" />
                <add name="X-Content-Type-Options" value="nosniff" />
                <add name="X-Frame-Options" value="SAMEORIGIN" />
                <add name="X-XSS-Protection" value="1" />
            </customHeaders>
        </httpProtocol>
```